# Keep getting a mutate error at the end with R

Tags: r

It will not read the titles:

```
d_df %>%
  mutate ( Year = substr(Date, 7, 10)) %>% 
  mutate(Structures = ifelse(ID %in% tnnls, "tunnelS", "bridges")) %>%
  filter( Year %in% yrs_wnt)  %>% 
  group_by(Year, Structures) %>% 
  summarise( Total = sum(EZPass)+ sum(Cash)) %>%
  pivot_wider (names_from= Structures, values_from= Total) %>%
  mutate( Percentb = (bridges / (tunnels + bridges)))
```

This is the error:

> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Year'. You can override using the
> `.groups` argument.

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `Percentb = (bridges/(tunnels + bridges))`.
> ℹ In group 1: `Year = "2012"`

I was expecting another column with the percent of bridges.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your sample dataFrame for better understanding.
It seems like the error arises due to the division by zero when calculating this:

`mutate( Percentb = (bridges / (tunnels + bridges)))`

You can handle it like this:

```
mutate(Percentb = ifelse((tunnels + bridges) == 0, 0, bridges / (tunnels + bridges)))
```